# TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function when trying to create a simple multple-choice in React-Native

Tags: react-native, multiple-choice

I am trying to create a simple multiple choice like that

'

```
use strict';

import React, {
    Component,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';

import MultipleChoice from 'rn-multiple-choice'

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MultipleChoice
                    options={[
                        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit',
                        'Lorem ipsum',
                        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.',
                        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur',
                        'Lorem ipsum dolor'
                        ]}
                    selectedOptions={['Lorem ipsum']}
                    maxSelectedOptions={2}
                    onSelection={(option)=>alert(option + ' was selected!')}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginTop: 60,
        margin: 20
    },
});

export default Home
```

But it gives me this erorr when I try to run it : TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

Somebody has any idea what the problem could be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot import React from react native, and Component as well, you can only

```
import React from 'react'
```

and as well do this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

React and React-native are separate imports.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but now it gives me an error:Invariant Violation: ListView has been removed from React Native. See https:/fb.me/nolistview for more information or use `deprecated-react-native-listview`. What should I do ?

Comment: @TiberiuPutinaru since you don't use any of those in your component, i guess it's from that multiple-choice library that's probably dead already, since ListView is deprecated,  you can remove the library and the component itself from your class and check, that should solve your current error

Comment: So I guess I should use another library instead ?

Comment: @TiberiuPutinaru yes, or might write those components yourself